# Creating a cookie pop up menu for ReactJS website

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I have a very simple website, which I will use just to promote my app. Users can put their emails to sign up for my news letter, also they can put reviews for my app.

I do not store any cookies (not login or anything) however I do use Google Analytics to store info for my website visitors. Every website I searched says Google Analytics is not GDPR complaint so I need to ask the user for their permission to store cookies (i.e. to use Google Analytics). So I have two questions:

1. Obviously I can create a pop up menu saying: "Hey, we are using Google Analytics cookies, they are optional, please accept them". What the actual text should be? Should I just copy-paste the text from some other website which uses Googe Analytics cookies?
2. What if the user rejects the Google Analytics cookies? I am not allowed to use Google Analytics to store info at all?
3. General question - if the user accepts the cookies, obviously I dont want to show the pop up menu, which asks for cookie permission, every time the user opens the website again and again. What do I do in such cases? Do I store cookie about cookie permission?